Why are transactions still valid for method calls of the same class?
I've been reading a lot of related questions on the internet, and they all say that there are no transactions for submethods for method calls of the same class. So after the following code is executed, there should be method2 in the database and no method1. but actually none of them are saved to the database.
spring boot 3.3.1
transactional default mode (proxy)
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Transactional
    public void add(AddInventoryChangeDto dto) {
        InventoryChange c = new InventoryChange();
        c.setName("method1");
        c.setCreateUserId("95a9d193354d19b833408d1c486f79c3");
        inventoryChangeMapper.insert(c);
        inStock();
    }

    private void inStock() {
        InventoryChange c = new InventoryChange();
        c.setName("method2");
        c.setCreateUserId("95a9d193354d19b833408d1c486f79c3");
        inventoryChangeMapper.insert(c);
        throw new RuntimeException("hh");
    }
}

@RestController
public class MyController {
  @Autowire
  private MyService service;

  @PostMapping("/test")
  public void test(@RequestBody AddInventoryChangeDto dto) {
    service.add(dto);
  }
}


If you are calling add() with a service proxy then both add() and it's call to inStock(() will be in the same transaction. You must use the proxy to start the transaction. How are you getting a handle to this class?

@LeeGreiner I've updated the code in the question

You are unconditionally throwing an exception at the end of inStock(). This will rollback the transaction and nothing is saved to the database as a result. Also, you aren't  using the repository save() method to persist your entities.
